# Aliasing column names in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

Is there a way in SQL server to alias column names for a particular table and store the aliases somewhere such that you can access the aliases while querying? I have a table where I cannot change column names and I am trying to figure out if there is a way to alias them to make them more user friendly.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail what you mean by "such that you can access the aliases while querying"? Why wouldn't a simple view that returns different column names suffice?

Comment: Create a view on the table with different column names.

Answer (score 6):

```
CREATE VIEW vw_RenameTable
AS
Begin

   Select GoodName1 = DumbName1
          ,GoodName2 = DumbName2
   From MyTable

End
```

Answer (score 0):

A view would be the natural answer to the question.  But, if you want to access the columns in the *same* table, you can use computed columns:

```
alter table mytable add bettercolumn as [Bad Ugly Name];
```

You can then use the computed column in a select *on the same table*.